# How to write if condition for mysql db data (condition: qty == 0 ) then email should be send to the admin

Tags: python, mysql, if-statement

In the below code I have made a route to /editproduct in this the products can be added, edit or delete the products. I want to send an email to the admin with an alert message as the product qty is 0 . when the product is edited to zero qty then the database updated with zero. if the qty in MySQL DB is zero then an email should send. how to write that condition. please help and sorry for the bad English grammar.

```
@app.route('/editProduct',methods = ['POST'])
def editProduct():
   if request.method == 'POST' and 'ProductID' in request.form and 'NEWProductName' in request.form and 'NEWProductDescription' in request.form and 'NEWProductQty':
      try:
         productID = request.form['ProductID']
         productName = request.form['NEWProductName']
         productDescription=request.form['NEWProductDescription']
         ProductQty=request.form['NEWProductQty']
         cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
         cursor.execute("UPDATE Products SET productName = % s,productDescription = % s, QTY = % s WHERE productID = % s",(productName,productDescription,ProductQty,productID) )
         #products = cursor.fetchone()
         #TEXT = "Hello "+username + ",\n\n"+ "the stock " +productName + "is empty" 
         #message  = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("Stock Alert", TEXT)
         mysql.connection.commit()
         cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
         QTY = "SELECT * from Products where QTY == 0;"
         cursor.execute(QTY)
         if QTY == 0:
             email_alert('prakprak2002@gmail.com')
         msg = "Product Edited "
         cursor.close()
      except:
         #con.rollback()
         msg = "error in operation"
      
      finally:
         return redirect(url_for('product', msg = msg))#+"?msg="+msg)
```

Comment: if you `UPDATE` `QTY` using `ProductQty` then you should check `if ProductQty == 0: email_alert(...)`

Comment: and if you want to cehk it with SELECT then you should select produce with `productID` and `fetch()` it and then check if this row of data has `row["QTY"] == 0`

Comment: Please provide a minimalistic sample of the code that can run and that reproduces the problem. At least include the used packages (imports) in your example.

Answer (score 0):

As for me you should simply use value from `HTML form` which you already have

```py
ProductQty = request.form['NEWProductQty']

if ProductQty == 0:
     email_alert('prakprak2002@gmail.com')
```

without using SQL query.

---

**EDIT:**

If you really want to waste time for checking in database then you should use `productID`

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT QTY from Products where productID == %s ;", (productID,)
    
row = cursor.fetchone()

#if row[0] == 0: 
if row["QTY"] == 0: 
     email_alert('prakprak2002@gmail.com')
```